# Is that possible to select values as columns in Clickhouse?

Tags: clickhouse

I have a table:

[image]

And I would like to make a query that returns Datastream Name values as a column:

[image]

Is that possible to achieve that with Clickhouse? Another thing to note - "Datastream name" column is not an enum/constant, it could be any string.

Thanks.

Comment: Look at these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bclickhouse%5D+transpose.

Comment: + https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bclickhouse%5D+pivot